# Angular 8 Observable.interval changed?

Tags: angular, rxjs, angular8

I am trying to use Observable.interval on angular 8 and it doesn't seem to like it.

First I import rxjs:

```
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
```

Then the code:

```
Observable.interval(1000).subscribe(x => {
    // something
  });
```

What is the angular 8 syntax?

Comment: `import { interval } from 'rxjs';` and you use it directly.

Comment: Note for the future: Be more precise than "it doesn't seem to like it" when asking questions. Look at the error you get and search for it on Google before. If you can't find anything, include it in the question on stackoverflow

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Can you try something like this:

```
import { interval } from 'rxjs';

interval(1000).subscribe(x => {
// something
});
```

Comment: That doesn't seem to work either .. says identifier expected

Comment: which version of rxjs do you use ?

Comment: Yeahh thanks.. it worked for me to call API in intervals

Answer (score 6):

you can use interval like below. It works in angular12 also.

```js
import { interval } from 'rxjs';

export class ObservableComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {
    intervalSubscription: Subscription;
    source = interval(1000);

    constructor() {}

    ngOnInit(): void {
        /*every 1second it emits value 0,1,2... 
        if we move to other component(destroy the component) it won't stop 
        incrementing and  another interval created along with the old 
        interval. Untill we unsubscribed it it 
        won't stop the incrementing process
        */
        this.intervalSubscription = this.source.subscribe(val => 
        console.log(val)); 
    }

    ngOnDestroy() {
        //when you move to another component, now the interval will be 
        //unsubscribed.
        this.intervalSubscription.unsubscribe();
    }    
}
```

Answer (score 3):

*// Use RxJS v6+ and emit value in sequence every 1 second

```
import { interval } from 'rxjs';
const source = interval(1000);
const subscribe = source.subscribe(val => console.log(val));
```

*//output: 0,1,2,3,4,5....*

Answer (score 3):

Use `timer` if you want to **wait n seconds before the first run** or **run it immediately** and then every n seconds.

Wait 3 seconds and then run every second:

```js
import { timer } from 'rxjs';

timer(3000, 1000).subscribe(x => {
// something
});
```

Run immediately and after that every 1 second (I don't know if this is the most elegant way to do it, but it's much simpler than other solutions I've seen, and it works):

```js
import { timer } from 'rxjs';

timer(0, 1000).subscribe(x => {
// something
});
```